# почему выводятся одни и те же данные из бд (php)

Tags: php, mysql, веб-программирование

Делаю пагитацию на сайте

Делая запрос sql **SELECT * from products WHERE id >= 4 ORDER BY price, id LIMIT 3**
mysql выдает данные у которых id >=4, логично все правильно, но мой php код выводит одни и те же строки, что на 1й странице что на 1n, в чем проблема? если убрать сортировку по price, тогда все ок, но с ней вот такая проблема. Помогите решить пожалуйста

```
$arr = [];
                $pag;

                if($_GET['show'])
                {
                    $pag = (($_GET['show']*$_GET['page'])-$_GET['show'])+1;
                    $main_query = "SELECT * from products WHERE id >= ".$pag;
                }
                else
                { 
                    $pag = ((9*$_GET['page'])-9)+1;
                    $main_query = "SELECT * from products";
                }

                if($_GET['sortby'] === "name")
                {
                    $query = "product_name";
                    array_push($arr, $query);
                }
                else if($_GET['sortby'] === "price")
                {
                    $query = "price";
                    array_push($arr, $query);
                }

                if($_GET['show'])
                {

                    $query = "id LIMIT ".$_GET['show'];
                    
                    array_push($arr, $query);
                }
                else
                {
                    $query = "id LIMIT 8";
                    
                    array_push($arr, $query);
                }

                $main_query .= " ORDER BY ";

                for($i = 0; $i < count($arr);$i++)
                {
                    if($i == count($arr)-1)
                    {
                        $main_query .= $arr[$i];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $main_query .= $arr[$i].", ";
                    }
                    
                }


                echo $main_query;
                $res = mysqli_query($connect, $main_query);

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
                {
                        echo '<a target="_blank" href="/pages/product-details.php?id='.$row['id'].'" class="product-cart">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="product-image"><img src="/images/'.$row['main_image_url'].'" alt=""></div>
                                    <div class="product-price-wrap">
                                        <div class="col">
                                            <div class="product-name">'.$row['product_name'].'</div>
                                            <div class="product-price">$ '.$row['price'].'</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>  
                            </a>';


                    }
```

Comment: вас через `$query = "id LIMIT ".$_GET['show'];` поломать можно

Comment: на что заменить, чтобы не поломали?

Comment: Чтобы не поломали -- превратить в число, как минимум.

Еще лучше что-то типа: prepare, bind_param, execute
(я сам mysqli не пробовал).

Еще, если продукты поудалять, будут пустые `id`.
В пару к `LIMIT` есть `OFFSET`.

Comment: всмысле если поудалять продукты, если я буду их удалять, я буду менять id

Comment: Не надо менять `id`, они не для этого; 
они для уникальной ид-ентификации, а не для сортировки.
Если у вас померла соседка, вам не меняют номер паспорта.

Comment: ну, сортировать по ним тоже можно, но скорее для однозначности, чтоб продукты с одинаковой ценой не ссорились, кто первее

Comment: вы меня не поняли) я не сортируб по id, я про то что вы говорите если я удалю товар, то все пойдет по п*****, я вам говорю, что если я удалю товар, я изменю авто инкремент в бд, а вы мне про соседку)

Comment: так всё у вас заработало?

Comment: угусь(бесит количество символов в ответе ааааааааа)